# jquery.pageless scrape

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll

I am using the jquery.pageless plugin. It implements infinite scrolling by grabbing the params generated by a paginate method in the controller.

I am trying to pass custom parameters, such as a user ID, to my pageless function. This works when I load the function in js.erb, as follows:

```
$('#relationship_list').pageless({ totalPages: "<%= @reviews.count %>"/5+1
                       , url: '/reviews'
                       , params: {id: "<%= params[:id] %>"}
                       , loaderMsg: "loading"
                       });
```

This works as desired. However, I DON'T want to load my page remotely, and so I need to find a way to implement this in javascript, unobtrusively (I don't want to integrate a script directly in my view, I want to place the code in application.js).

That means I have to find a way to 'translate' code like <%=params=> to a variable that the pageless call can read from the controller. But how? I really have no idea how to do this.

I think this is a question best for people who know jquery.pageless already, and since it's so general there's no point in my adding my own code to this post - please comment if disagree!

Comment: ["Has anyone else used `x`" questions are not suitable for Stack Overflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) What is your **actual** question?

Comment: OK thanks @MattBall, that helped me understand better what my own goals are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I picked. Any tips on whether this was the appropriate way to go is welcome:

```
if($('#relationship_list').length){
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/users/'+$('.user_info').attr("id"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                $('#relationship_list').pageless({ url: '/reviews'
                                , totalPages: response["count"]/5+1
                                , loaderMsg: "loading"
                                , params: {id: response["id"]}
                });
            }
    });     
}
```

What this does is make an ajax call to the controller, and render a json param with the key parameters. I then use these parameters to implement the .pageless function.

Note that in order to get the original user ID I actually have a div that contains the user ID, and so I grab that from the page. The user ID is no state secret but **if anyone has a tip on how to grab an html parameter** (the ID is in params[:id] in my rails code) I would be super grateful